# Cannot toggle Bool in loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm working with UICollectionView with my model data.
I have this model data prepared

```
struct Room {
        let type: String
        let position: String
        var hidden: Bool?

        static let typeA = "A"
        static let typeB = "B"
        static let typeC = "C"

        static let positionA = "A"
        static let positionB = "B"
        static let positionC = "C"

        static var rooms = [
            Room(type: typeA, position: positionA, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeA, position: positionB, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeA, position: positionC, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeB, position: positionA, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeB, position: positionB, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeB, position: positionC, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeC, position: positionA, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeC, position: positionB, hidden: false),
            Room(type: typeC, position: positionC, hidden: false)
        ]
    }
```

for UICollectionViewCells. What I need to do is toggle `hidden` bool value so it can filter cells with this

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
    if Room.rooms[indexPath.row].hidden == true {
      cell.layer.opacity = 0.5
    }
```

and to do so, I have this function in `Room` struct

```
  static func toggleHidden(whichOne: String) {
    if var roomType = rooms.type {
      if roomType.type == whichOne || roomType.position == whichOne {
        roomType.hidden = true
      }
    }
  }
```

But it throws an error:

`Cannot assign to 'hidden' in 'roomType'`

I can do something like this

```
  static func toggleHidden(whichOne: Int) {
    (rooms[whichOne].hidden == false) ? (rooms[whichOne].hidden = true) : (rooms[whichOne].hidden = false)
  }
```

However, it needs to filter by String so that multiple items can be toggled at once. What I'm doing is to toggle `hidden` bool of all items which have `whichOne` string.

Is this approach not smart first of all...? Any advice would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: `Room` is a class/struct having a variable `rooms` holding `Room` objects??? Very confusing and unpredictable in the errors it could produce.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, updated code.

Answer (score 1):

In `roomType.hidden = true`, you are trying to assign true/false to a variable of type `String` (typeA, typeB etc. are strings).

Perhaps you mean `room.hidden`.

To set all rooms of typeA to hidden:

```
var typeARooms = rooms.filter { $0.type == typeA }
for room in typeARooms { room.hidden = true }
collectionView.reloadData()  // not animated
```

Comment: This looks so nice but it throws the same error, `Cannot assign to 'hidden' in 'roomType'`...

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to Mundi's answer but you should do the following

```
    var typeARooms = Room.rooms.filter { $0.type == "A" }
    for var i = 0; i < typeARooms.count; i++ {
        var room = typeARooms[i]
        room.hidden = true
    }
```

For-in loops elements are read-only (let variables). Which is why you need to explicitly use `var` to be able to modify the struct.

Comment: Somehow that still throws `Cannot assign to`... error. Am I missing something basic...?

Comment: You are using ``let`` instead of ``var`` somewhere. That is the reason why that error occurs. I ran my code in Xcode without any issues using the Room struct you supplied. let == immutable, var == mutable

Comment: Cleared cache and eventually the code worked, sorry about this. However, it seems that function you provided copies elements equals "A" from `room` array into `typeARooms`, then set bools to true. Is there someway that you can directly change bools in `rooms` array? This is because I only would like to change the opacity of the UICollectionViewCell that matches keyword while retaining all the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up like this:

```
  static func toggleHidden(whichOne: String) {
    for index in 0..<rooms.count {
      if rooms[index].type == whichOne || rooms[index].position == whichOne {
        !rooms[index].isHidden ? (rooms[index].isHidden = true) : (rooms[index].isHidden = false)
      }
    }
  }
```

Wish I could make it shorter but it just works. This way if I do `self.collectionView?.reloadData()`, CollectionView applies changes as expected.
This is based on your advices, thanks a lot.

Comment: This is in effect my the logic of my answer. I also provide a way to shorten it with `filter`. You should click the accept answer checkmark.

Comment: I've simplified my code and testing your code on playground but still it does not compile... [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/0IvxS03.jpg)